# AWS Lambda randomly get Operation timeout in 50ms

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, sequelize.js

I'm running nodejs with sequelize on Lambda, my config:

```
    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 20000,
        idle: 10000
    }
```

Env:

```
Node: 10.x
Sequelize: 6.3.5
```

```
ERROR   Unhandled Promise Rejection 
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection",
    "errorMessage": "SequelizeConnectionAcquireTimeoutError: Operation timeout",
    "reason": {
        "errorType": "SequelizeConnectionAcquireTimeoutError",
        "errorMessage": "Operation timeout",
        "name": "SequelizeConnectionAcquireTimeoutError",
        "parent": {
            "errorType": "Error",
            "errorMessage": "Operation timeout",
            "stack": [
                "Error: Operation timeout",
                "    at Timeout._timeout.setTimeout (/var/task/node_modules/sequelize-pool/lib/Deferred.js:17:25)",
                "    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)",
                "    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)",
                "    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)",
                "    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)"
            ]
        },
        "original": {
            "errorType": "Error",
            "errorMessage": "Operation timeout",
            "stack": [
                "Error: Operation timeout",
                "    at Timeout._timeout.setTimeout (/var/task/node_modules/sequelize-pool/lib/Deferred.js:17:25)",
                "    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)",
                "    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)",
                "    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)",
                "    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)"
            ]
        },
        "stack": [
            "SequelizeConnectionAcquireTimeoutError: Operation timeout",
            "    at ConnectionManager.getConnection (/var/task/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:288:48)"
        ]
    },
    "promise": {},
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: SequelizeConnectionAcquireTimeoutError: Operation timeout",
        "    at process.on (/var/runtime/index.js:37:15)",
        "    at process.emit (events.js:198:13)",
        "    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)",
        "    at emitPromiseRejectionWarnings (internal/process/promises.js:140:18)",
        "    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:69:34)"
    ]
}
```

I also have another Lambda function with the same exact settings (but with node 12 instead of node 10), which handle much more request per hour, but less executions per request, and it work perfectly fine.

**The problem is this Lambda function only timeout once in a while, and it got timeout only after 10-50ms**
I don't know how this happened. No transaction used in code. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The pool setting should be `acquireTimeoutMillis`, but the error you are seeing comes from trying to acquire a connection from the pool. The default timeout is 30s.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who encountered this error. In my case, after you established a connection to your database, any unhandled error will not be logged to stack trace, and this error is returned.

I think this was caused by Nodejs trying to close the connection.